# How to prove that $f(x)$ is constant if $|f(x)-f(y)|^2 \le (x-y)^3$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $\mathbb R$ be the set of real numbers and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be such that for all $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R$ $|f(x)-f(y)|^2 \le (x-y)^3$. How can we prove that $f(x)$ is constant?

I have a feeling that this has something to do with first principles of differentiation but am not able to get it. I would prefer an intuition based approach!

Comment: Should your right-hand side be something like $|x-y|^3$ rather than $(x-y)^3$? Otherwise, taking $x=0$ and $y=1$, your function needs to satisfy $|f(0) - f(1)|^2 \leq -1$, which is obviously problematic.

Comment: Interesting variation on the more usual (and asked several times on the site) condition that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant C\cdot(x-y)^2$. The take-home message is that no differentiation is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x\neq y$ but near $y$, so you can divide lhs by $(x-y)^2$ and observe that the derivative of $f$ equals $0$ for all $x$. Than you have f constant.

Comment: Sorry, you should divide all the inequality by $(x-y)^2$ and then you proceed. When you make $x\longrightarrow y$ you will find the answer.

Answer (score 4):

For $y\ne x$, we have
$$
\varlimsup\limits_{y\to x}\dfrac{|f(x)−f(y)|^2}{|x-y|^2}\leqslant\varlimsup\limits_{y\to x}|x−y|=0
$$
So $|f'(x)|^2=0$ and $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

And thus $f(x)=c.$

Comment: What does $\varlimsup$ mean in comparison to $\lim$

Comment: $\varlimsup$ is known as upper limit. Compared to $\lim$, it always exists while $\lim$ exists iff $\varlimsup=\varliminf$.

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that $\varlimsup_{y\to x}$ is the same as $\displaystyle\lim_{y \to x^+}$?

Comment: No, it is not right.

Comment: It is not the same thing as $\displaystyle\limsup_{y\to x}$ is it?

Comment: No. $\lim\limits_{y→x^+}$ is known as right limit. It happens only when $y\to x$ from the right.

Answer (score 3):

The condition should be $|f(x) - f(y)|^2 \le \color{red}{|}x - y\color{red}{|}^3$ for all $x, y\in \Bbb R$. Fix $a,b \in \Bbb R$ with $b > a$. For every positive integer $n$,

\begin{align}
|f(b) - f(a)| &\le \sum_{k = 1}^n \left|f\left(a + k\frac{b-a}{n}\right) - f\left(a + (k-1)\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\right| \\
&\le \sum_{k = 1}^n \left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)^{3/2}\\
&= \frac{(b-a)^{3/2}}{n^{1/2}}.
\end{align}

Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$, we deduce $|f(b) - f(a)| = 0$, i.e., $f(a) = f(b)$.